# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_111.0.5563

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy

when I want to using proxy in selenium `selenium==4.1.0` on M1 macbook pro, shows error info:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 111.0.5563
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 111.0.5563 google-chrome
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 371, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 920, in _tunnel
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_111.0.5563 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/pydolphin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_111.0.5563 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the Python code how to set the proxy:

```
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # option.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
    option.add_argument("--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:7890")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=option)
    driver.get("https://accounts.example.com/SignUp")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

why still shows could not access the proxy? I am sure the proxy address `127.0.0.1:7890` works fine with the google chrome browser.